# Getting a "not a single-group group function" error, tried researching it

Tags: sql

I'm taking a database summer course so I'm new at this. Here is my code. I'm trying to display the average price for each type of book in my database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, AVG(price) AS AVERAGE_PRICE

FROM book

ORDER BY type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to select data (`type`) in a grouped query. The `AVG` function causes the query to be grouped, but the whole result is a single group as you haven't specified anything to group by.

To get the average for each type of book, you need to group on the type:

```
SELECT type, AVG(price) AS AVERAGE_PRICE
FROM book
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type;
```

Comment: It worked, thought I had tried that. Was DISTINCT messing me up?

Comment: @DustyHawkins: Not really, it was selecting `type` that caused the error. Having `DISTINCT` is pointless once you have grouped the query, as each row will have different values for `type`.